# Should I replace "me" and "I" with "he" or "she" when quoting?

Tags: american-english, quotes, quotations, quotation-marks

If I quote someone saying "me" or "I", when I quote them should I replace them with "he" or "she"?

For example, if someone says:

> I went to the movies.

Should I quote that like this:

> He/she said "He/she went to the movies".

Or this:

> He/she said "I went to the movies".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your third example is correct. Quotes are composed of two parts; the speaker tag to identify the speaker, and the actual quote itself. For example:

> Einstein said "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."

Or for your example:

> Sally said "I went to the movies."

But you can also paraphrase what they said and integrate it into the sentence without quotes, such as:

> Sally said she went to the movies.

You would certainly never use your example of *Sally said "Sally went to the movies"*, because Sally did not in fact say that. When quoting, everything inside the quotes must be what the person said.

Comment: Well, there _might_ be another Sally there, but the context is clear and that's just nitpicking.

Answer (score 7):

If you are supplying a direct quote, you quote the subject exactly.

If you are paraphrasing, then you can change the pronouns to make things more consistent.

An example of a direct quote:

> When asked what he did last night, Dave said "I was at the movies."

Paraphrased, it would look like this:

> When I asked Dave what he did last night, he said he was at the movies.